# CSS not styling page but is loaded in DOM

Tags: css, laravel, homestead

#### Hello there ladies and gentlemen.

I've got quite the puzzler going on. I have just installed a fresh instance of Laravel (5.1) on a Vagrant (1.7.4) machine in Windows (10). The weird thing is that I'm linking both the external stylesheet and javascript the same way:

`<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css">`

`<script src="{!! URL::asset('js/all.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The problem is that the styles are not being applied (cross-browser) to the elements. I'm not getting any errors in the console. When I look at the head of the document I can see that it's the right path:

`<link href="http://laravel.dev/css/app.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css">`

`<script src="http://laravel.dev/js/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I have a standard Laravel file structure with the CSS and JS folders inside the public folder. If I look at the sources tab inside Chrome developer tools, I can see that the JavaScript file is being loaded but there is no sign of the CSS file. But if I right-click on the link for the CSS file, and open link in new tab, I can see the CSS. I have tried explicitly changing the character encoding type to UTF-8 both as an attribute in the link tag as well as the first line of the css itself with the @charset 'at rule'. Here are some illustrations:

Thanks for your help.

[image: Styles not found]

[image: Link tag with correct href attribute]

[image: Style are loaded in DOM but are not applied]

[image: No errors in console and JavaScript is outputting code]

[image: Not being loaded]

[image: Not being loaded]

Comment: could it be that you simply deactivated css styles in the browser by accident (maybe with a key command)?

Comment: i bet this is a browser issue, try a different browser - or a different machine if possible. (if you can access your css from your page source)

Comment: I've tried it in all major browsers and they're all the same. This leads me to believe that it's either a Laravel issue or a Vagrant/Homestead issue.

Comment: what about that (commented) last line in the CSS: `sourceMappingURL=app.css.map`  ? Maybe you have to add `.map`to your link? (I don't know Lavarel, I am guessing and would just try this...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your css-link you have `rel="stylesheets"` (plural). It should be `rel="stylesheet"` (singular) :)

Comment: If that's the issue, I'm going to face palm! I'll check tomorrow when I get to work.

Comment: @MrGrigri That's definitely the reason :).

Comment: Well, much to my disbelief, It was in fact that very reason :facepalm: Sometime having a second pair of eyes really does help. Thanks